# Not able to upload video/photos taken from custom camera app

Tags: android, video, file-upload, camera, photo

My custom camera app basically shoots video and photos.These photos or videos are to be uploaded to my server. When I try uploading photos/videos from gallery, I am able to upload the files without any issue. When I try to upload a photo or video right after taking them from camera, I don't get any error (Server response code is 200), but the file is not getting uploaded. i.e I could not find the file on server like how my photos/videos from gallery appear on server once I give upload. And also my video thumbnail preview is blank ( contains nothing ) soon after the video is recorded. Here is my code snippets where I guess I would have made a mistake.

MyCamera.class

```
 //imports done
    public class MyCamera extends Activity implements OnClickListener,
            OnTouchListener {

        private CameraSurface view;
        static ImageView gallery;

        String upload_type_TAG = "";

        final static int PIC_CHOOSE = 100;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            view = new CameraSurface(this, null);
            setContentView(R.layout.camera_view);


            ......

            }

        public void startVideoRecorder() {
            if (isRecording == true) {
                if (view.prepareVideoRecorder()) {
                    System.out.println("Prepared");
                    view.mMediaRecorder.start();
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Video Recording");
        }

        public void captureImage() {
            CameraSurface.takePic();
            System.out.println("Image Capture");
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
               //calls intent to choose pic or video from gallery
            ...made necessary calls
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            //based on different touch durations I call
            //functions to take pic or shoot video 
            ...made necessary calls
        }

    //called whenever a pic is shot or video is recorded
        static void callDirectUploadActivity(File pictureFile, Context ctx) {
            System.out.println("Upload activity called");
            Uri filePath = Uri.fromFile(pictureFile);
            String value= pictureFile.getAbsolutePath();
            Intent i = new Intent(ctx, DirectUpload.class);
            i.putExtra("file_path", filePath.toString());
            i.putExtra("uploadFilePath", value);
            System.out.println("Dialog stopped showing");
            dialog.dismiss();
            ctx.startActivity(i);
        }

        //called when image / video has to be choosen from gallery
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            switch (requestCode) {
            case PIC_CHOOSE:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    Uri path=data.getData();
                    String filePath=getRealPathFromURI(MyCamera.this, path);
                    File f=new File(filePath);
                    //Uri selectedImg = data.getData();
                    //String selectedImage=getRealPathFromURI(MyCamera.this, selectedImg);
                    Uri selectedImage=Uri.fromFile(f);
                    Intent i = new Intent(MyCamera.this, DirectUpload.class);
                    i.putExtra("file_path", selectedImage.toString());
                    i.putExtra("uploadFilePath", filePath);
                    System.out.println("Dialog stopped showing");
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                break;
            }
        }

        //for taking videos (view is CameraSurface.class)
        public void startVideoRecorder() {
        if (isRecording == true) {
            if (view.prepareVideoRecorder()) {
                System.out.println("Prepared");
                view.mMediaRecorder.start();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Video Recording");
    }

    //for taking photos
    public void captureImage() {
        CameraSurface.takePic();
        System.out.println("Image Capture");
    }

        public String getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
            Cursor cursor = null;
            try {
                String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null,
                        null, null);
                int column_index = cursor
                        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                return cursor.getString(column_index);
            } finally {
                if (cursor != null) {
                    cursor.close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

CameraSurface.class

```
  public class CameraSurface extends SurfaceView implements OnTouchListener {

        static Context ctx;

        public CameraSurface(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);

            ctx = context;

            if (surface_holder == null) {
                surface_holder = this.getHolder();
            }

            sh_callback = my_callback();
            surface_holder.addCallback(sh_callback);

            setOnTouchListener(this);
        }

        public static void takePic() {

            System.out.println("Take pic called");

            final PictureCallback mPicture = new PictureCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

                    System.out.println("Photo taken");

                    File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);

                    if (pictureFile == null) {
                        return;
                    }

                    try {
                        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                        fos.write(data);
                        fos.close();
                        mCamera.stopPreview();
                        mCamera.startPreview();
                        String u = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(
                                ctx.getContentResolver(),
                                pictureFile.getAbsolutePath(),
                                pictureFile.getName(), pictureFile.getName());
                        System.out.println("URL:" + u);
                        processImage(pictureFile.toString());
                        MyCamera.callDirectUploadActivity(pictureFile, ctx);

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };

            mCamera.takePicture(null, null, null, mPicture);

        }

        private static void processImage(String u) throws IOException {
            System.out.println("Decode Starts Here");
            Bitmap temp,image;
            Matrix mat = new Matrix();
            mat.setRotate(90);
            String path = u;
            image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
            int x = image.getWidth();
            int y = image.getHeight();
            temp = Bitmap.createBitmap(image, 0, 0, x, y, mat, true);
            ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            temp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
            File f1 = new File(path.toString());
            try {
                f1.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            FileOutputStream fos = null;
            try {
                fos = new FileOutputStream(f1);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                fos.write(bytes.toByteArray());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            fos.close();

        }

        public static void processVideo(){
            System.out.println("Video taken");

            File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO);

            if (pictureFile == null) {
                return;
            }
            try {
                MyCamera.callDirectUploadActivity(pictureFile, ctx);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public static String getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
            Cursor cursor = null;
            try {
                String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null,
                        null, null);
                int column_index = cursor
                        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                return cursor.getString(column_index);
            } finally {
                if (cursor != null) {
                    cursor.close();
                }
            }
        }

        boolean prepareVideoRecorder() {

            int videoWidth = mCamera.getParameters().getPreviewSize().width;
            int videoHeight = mCamera.getParameters().getPreviewSize().height;

            mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

            mCamera.unlock();
            mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);

            mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(90);


            mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
            mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);


            mMediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile
                    .get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_LOW));


            mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO)
                    .toString());


            mMediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(this.getHolder().getSurface());

            try {
                mMediaRecorder.prepare();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                Log.d(TAG,
                        "IllegalStateException preparing MediaRecorder: "
                                + e.getMessage());
                releaseMediaRecorder();
                return false;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "IOException preparing MediaRecorder: " + e.getMessage());
                releaseMediaRecorder();
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }

        void releaseMediaRecorder() {
            if (mMediaRecorder != null) {
                mMediaRecorder.reset();
                mMediaRecorder.release();
                mMediaRecorder = null;

                processVideo();

            }
        }

        private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type) {
            System.out.println("Function CALLED");

            File mediaStorageDir = new File(
                    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "");

            if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
                if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                    System.out.println("No directory!!");
                    return null;
                }
            }

            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")
                    .format(new Date());
            File mediaFile;
            if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) {
                System.out.println("image mode");
                mediaFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + "/directory/" + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");

                System.out.println(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + "/directory/" + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
            } else if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
                System.out.println("video mode");

                mediaFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + "/directory/" + "VID_" + timeStamp + ".mp4");

                ContentValues cv=new ContentValues(3);
            cv.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE,"VID_" + timeStamp + ".mp4");
            cv.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA,Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + "/iCop/Videos/" + "VID_" + timeStamp + ".mp4");
            cv.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.MIME_TYPE,"video/mp4");
            ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + "/directupload/" + "VID_" + timeStamp + ".mp4", MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
            ctx.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, cv);

                System.out.println(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + "/directory/" + "VID_" + timeStamp + ".mp4");

            } else {
                System.out.println("null returned");
                return null;
            }
            return mediaFile;
        }

        SurfaceHolder.Callback my_callback() {
            SurfaceHolder.Callback ob1 = new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {

                @Override
                public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                    mCamera.stopPreview();
                    mCamera.release();
                    mCamera = null;
                }

                @Override
                public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                    mCamera = Camera.open();
                    mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
                    try {
                        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
                    } catch (IOException exception) {
                        mCamera.release();
                        mCamera = null;
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format,
                        int width, int height) {
                    mCamera.startPreview();
                }
            };
            return ob1;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    //just some cool stuff, nothing related to taking pics/videos
            System.out.println("Touched");

            }
    }
```

DirectUpload.class

```
public class DirectUpload extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    String uploadFilePath;
    String uploadServerUri;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        uploadServerUri ="" ;//server url given correctly
        getIntentData();
        bUpload.setOnClickListener(this);
        bCancel.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void getIntentData() {
        try {
            Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
            uploadFilePath=b.getString("uploadfilepath");
            String path = b.getString("file_path");
            Uri u = Uri.parse(b.getString("file_path"));
            Uri parsUri=Uri.parse(path);

            //Photo preview working correctly for both pics taken
           //from camera and pics chosen from gallery
            if (path.endsWith(".jpg") || path.endsWith(".jpeg") || path.endsWith(".png") || path.endsWith(".gif") || path.contains("images")) {
                ivPreview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Bitmap d = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(
                        this.getContentResolver(), u);
                int nh = (int) (d.getHeight() * (512.0 / d.getWidth()));
                Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(d, 512, nh, true);
                ivPreview.setImageBitmap(scaled);
                System.out.println("Image uploading");
            } else {

                //Video preview working correctly for gallery videos 
                //but not working for videos shot with came
                File f=new File(u.toString());

                ivPreview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                String projection[]={
                    MediaStore.Video.Media._ID,MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA  
                };

                Cursor videoCursor=this.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection, MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA+" like ? ", 
                        new String[]{"%/"+testFile.getName()}, null);

                Log.i("Cursor count", videoCursor.getCount()+"");

                videoCursor.moveToFirst();

                int idIndex=videoCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media._ID);

                int id=videoCursor.getInt(idIndex);

                Bitmap curThumb = MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(getContentResolver(),id, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);

                videoCursor.close();
                ivPreview.setImageBitmap(curThumb);

                System.out.println("Video uploading");
            }
            File f=new File(path);

            filepath_name = u.toString();

            } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public String getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null,
                    null, null);
            int column_index = cursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.bUpload) {
            description = etDescription.getText();
            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(DirectUpload.this, "",
                    "Uploading file", true);
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    uploadFile(uploadFilePath);
                }
            }).start();
        } else if (v.getId() == R.id.bCancel) {
            finish();
        }
    }

 //upload code 200 OK but photos/videos taken from camera not found in server
 //photos/videos from gallery uploaded successfully

public void uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {

        String fileName = sourceFileUri;

        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        DataOutputStream dos = null; 
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "*****";
        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
        File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);

        if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {

             dialog.dismiss();

             Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :"+filepath_name);


             return ;

        }
        else
        {
             try {

                   // open a URL connection to the Servlet
                 FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
                 URL url = new URL(uploadServerUri);

                 // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
                 conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                 conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
                 conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
                 conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
                 conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                 conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                 conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
                 conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                 conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName);

                 dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

                 dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                 dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                                           + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);

                 dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                 // create a buffer of  maximum size
                 bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

                 bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                 buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                 // read file and write it into form...
                 bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize); 

                 while (bytesRead > 0) {

                   dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                   bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                   bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                   bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);  

                  }

                 // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
                 dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                 dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                 // Responses from the server (code and message)
                 int serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                 String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

                 Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : "
                         + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

                 //close the streams //
                 fileInputStream.close();
                 dos.flush();
                 dos.close();
            } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
                dialog.dismiss(); 
                ex.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex); 
            } catch (Exception e) {
                dialog.dismiss(); 
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("Upload file to server Exception", "Exception : "  + e.getMessage(), e); 
            }
            dialog.dismiss();      

         } // End else block
       }
}
```

I could not figure out where I could have possibly gone wrong. Please help me get through this, I am new to Android.

Answer (score 1):

Got my mistake. I have called the method *getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO)* twice. First time its called in *prepareVideoRecorder()* (where the recorded video is actually written). Second time I call it from *processVideo()* method (where I create a new file without any data in it). Remove the second function call (to *getOutputMediaFile()*), problem solved.